# Generate identical positve going and negative going pulses/spikes at the same time

Tags: passive-networks, pulse, tesla-coil

I am interested in building a circuit to generate a sharp positive pulse and an identical negative pulse at the same time with a peak of about 10 to 200 V. So when I say sharp I would like a rise time of 10 ns or better. The pulse could drop off over a longer timescale and I don't care too much about the actual pulse shape, I just want the pulses to be equal and opposite.

I can supply an input pulse of 0-200 V (from 0 to +200V) and was trying to think of a way using passive components, capacitors and resistors, to differentiate the pulse or something to get +ve and -ve outputs at the same time, but, I can only think of ways to generate a shark positive spike at the beginning of the pulse and a sharp negative spike at the end of the pulse.

So my next thought is some sort of Tesla coil type inductive thing, but I worry that would slow down the pulse and ring.

I guess I may have to think of some active circuit with FETs driven by the same input pulse, but if there is a passive way to do it I would be interested as it might be easier to match the shapes of the positive and negative spikes.

(I looked, but didn't find a similar previous question)

The application is for these two pulses to go onto two separated electrodes for one of two scenarios. 1) to have the pulses go onto plates to generate an electric field so capacitance I estimate as maybe up to 50 pF but probably less - my best guess is 10 pF.  Pulse length of 1 to 10 μs perhaps with close to zero current. 2) to have the pulses go onto two electrodes that are so close together that an arc is formed for a very short time. The arc does not have to be powerful. For arc the pulse length could be as short as 10 ns with a repetition frequency of ~1 kHz and it does not have to be powerful. In fact, given the choice, a weaker arc might be better than a strong one. Again I anticipate a low capacitance of ~10 to 50 pF.

Comment: Can't you just feed your pulse into a suitable transformer? Two identical secondaries will give you identical pulses, and you can connect them as needed to get the polarities you want.

Comment: A pulse transformer with a center tap secondary will give you the symmetrical output you want but a 10 nano-second rise time to 200 volts may not be possible with available materials. An active solution seems more achievable.

Comment: @DaveTweed - ok great, many thanks - if that will work on the timescales I need then that would be ideal. Do you want to expand that a little bit as an answer?

Comment: @Dan1138 thanks ok the centre tap makes sense - so I guess the centre goes to ground and the two ends give the +ve and -ve pulse. Many thanks for the suggestion - do you want to put that as an answer so I can mark this as solved?

Comment: Tom, I doubt my comment is the answer you seek. I suspect that the pulse transformer output rise time will be much longer than 10 nanoseconds.

Comment: @Dan1138 how about https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/336/Pulse%20h1164-1199343.pdf - if I see it correctly it goes to 1.5 kV at 100 MHz

Comment: Tom, that is a data sheet for Ethernet coupling transformers. The 1.5 KV specification is for isolation voltage between the primary and secondary. The transformer is optimized for low voltage signals from  ±3 to ±5 volts. A 200 volt pulse on the primary may vaporize it.

Comment: @Dan1138 - thanks I thought it was probably too good to be true

Comment: Never design a signal or power generator without load capacitance and current specs. why?  Ic=CdV/dt then Tau=L/R or RC or ? Also define purpose.  And look at ignition ccts

Comment: High-power [baluns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balun) operating at 100 MHz or more are not a big deal in the amateur radio community. If you can generate the pulse in the first place, you can generate its mirror image.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 - many thanks, thougn not sure I 100% understand - will have to look up ignition ccts

Comment: @DaveTweed many thanks for the link - I really appreciate that.

Comment: 10 ns=Tr = 0.35/BW and SRF >> BW = 350MHz  so what is current, or load capacitance?  power, not trivial. unless you use arc gap and arc pulse dump

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75. I was imagining two scenarios. 1) to have the pulses go onto plates to generate an electric field so capacitance I estimate as maybe up to 50 pF but probably less - my best guess is 10 pF. 2) to have the pulses go onto two electrodes that are so close together that an arc is formed.

Comment: In any case you have to define the capacitance to know how to generate this C=dV/(dt*I)

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 thanks for your help. So for 10 ns 200 V and 10 pF I need 200 mA for 10 ns I guess....